# Deploying simple Django application to Google App Engine taking 30 minutes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm evaluating GAE for a new project. I'm deploying a very simple Django app to GAE Flexible and I'm finding it takes about 30 minutes to deploy. The actual build step takes just a few seconds, but it gets stuck on "Updating service [default]..." for a very long time. I'm deploying via the shell using "gcloud app deploy". This happens even after the first deploy. I don't see anything in the logs.

Comment: This happens from time to time.  Probably not a problem with your code.  Caused by Google maintenance or concurrent traffic.  Is it still happening?

Comment: I don't know, I ended up deleting the whole thing and just moving to AWS. The problem persisted over several hours and combined with some other strange errors I was experiencing caused more frustration than it was worth. Even creating an issue in their issue tracker caused a cryptic error that I couldn't figure out! Just doesn't seem ready for primetime if you ask me. Anyways, sorry for the rant and thanks for your help.